# No universal upper bound for $\mathbb{E}[\text{max}_{k \leq n}X_k]$ for nonnegatve submartingale

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales

I want to see that there is no universal constant $C$ such that for every non-negative martingale $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$, we have that $\mathbb{E}[\text{max}_{k \leq n}X_k] \leq C\mathbb{E}[X_n]$.

I've tried to do a few things with constructing a sufficiently fastly increasing submartingale but nothing has really panned out so far. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: For an increasing submartingale the inequality holds  with $C=1$.

Comment: Hint: Double-or-nothing martingale is a counterexample to show that there is no finite universal C.

Comment: @E-A what is the exact form for the double or nothing martingale? Looking online I can't seem to find a straight formulation and a bunch of gambling stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the example mentioned in comments: let $X_0=1$, $X_{n+1}=2X_n$ with probability $1/2$ and $X_{n+1}=0$ with probability $1/2$. Then

$$\mathsf{E}\left(X_{n+1}\mid X_1,\ldots,X_n\right)=X_n$$

so $(X_n)$ is a martingale. In particular, $\mathsf{E} X_n=\mathsf{E} X_0=1$. On the other hand

$$\mathsf{E}\left(\max_{0\le k\le n} X_k\right)=\sum_{t=0}^{n-1} 2^t (2^{-t}-2^{-(t+1)})+1=\frac{n}{2}+1$$

Comment: ...I should have guessed that was the definition of a "double-or-nothing" martingale. I feel dumb now. Thanks for the help!